# Fastest way to query a Map of Integers to extract related Linked Integers

Tags: c#

I am writing code for an embedded device, I have a map of numbers, shown below is a subset ranging from 151 to 66, the adjacent numbers are linked numbers, so for `151`, its linked numbers would be `150 - 148 - 146 - 136 - 131 - 91 -` and so on, I have a method which accepts two parameters `int startNum` and `int endNum` and the goal is to return an array containing 2 integers which will link me from `startNum to endNum`, so for an example see below

```
startNum = 126
endNum = 75
```

`linked nums would be 105,90, since 126 brings me to 105, 105 brings me to 90 and 90 takes me to 75`, and there are several other paths which will do this, my question is is it possible to figure out these linked numbers without using nested for loops and testing every possible combination.

```
151 = 150 - 148 - 146 - 136 - 131 - 91 - 
150 = 149 - 147 - 145 - 135 - 130 - 90 - 
149 = 148 - 146 - 144 - 134 - 129 - 89 - 
148 = 147 - 145 - 143 - 133 - 128 - 88 - 
147 = 146 - 144 - 142 - 132 - 127 - 87 - 
146 = 143 - 139 - 137 - 127 - 125 - 89 - 
145 = 144 - 142 - 140 - 130 - 125 - 85 - 
144 = 143 - 141 - 139 - 129 - 124 - 84 - 
143 = 142 - 140 - 138 - 128 - 123 - 83 - 
142 = 141 - 139 - 137 - 127 - 122 - 82 - 
141 = 140 - 138 - 136 - 126 - 121 - 81 - 
140 = 139 - 137 - 135 - 125 - 120 - 80 - 
139 = 136 - 132 - 130 - 120 - 118 - 82 - 
138 = 137 - 135 - 133 - 123 - 118 - 78 - 
137 = 136 - 134 - 132 - 122 - 117 - 77 - 
136 = 135 - 133 - 131 - 121 - 116 - 76 - 
135 = 134 - 133 - 132 - 131 - 130 - 129 -
134 = 133 - 131 - 129 - 119 - 114 - 74 - 
133 = 132 - 130 - 128 - 118 - 113 - 73 - 
132 = 131 - 130 - 129 - 128 - 127 - 126 -
131 = 130 - 128 - 126 - 116 - 111 - 71 - 
130 = 129 - 127 - 125 - 115 - 110 - 70 - 
129 = 126 - 122 - 120 - 110 - 108 - 72 - 
128 = 127 - 125 - 124 - 116 - 110 - 74 - 
127 = 126 - 124 - 122 - 112 - 107 - 67 - 
126 = 123 - 119 - 117 - 107 - 105 - 69 - 
125 = 124 - 123 - 122 - 121 - 120 - 119 -
124 = 123 - 121 - 119 - 109 - 104 - 64 - 
123 = 120 - 116 - 114 - 104 - 102 - 66 - 
122 = 121 - 119 - 118 - 110 - 104 - 68 - 
121 = 120 - 118 - 116 - 106 - 101 - 61 - 
120 = 119 - 117 - 115 - 105 - 100 - 60 - 
119 = 116 - 112 - 110 - 100 - 98 - 62 - 
118 = 117 - 115 - 113 - 103 - 98 - 58 - 
117 = 116 - 114 - 112 - 102 - 97 - 57 - 
116 = 115 - 113 - 111 - 101 - 96 - 56 - 
115 = 112 - 108 - 106 - 96 - 94 - 58 - 
114 = 113 - 111 - 109 - 99 - 94 - 54 - 
113 = 112 - 110 - 108 - 98 - 93 - 53 - 
112 = 111 - 109 - 107 - 97 - 92 - 52 - 
111 = 108 - 104 - 102 - 92 - 90 - 54 - 
110 = 109 - 107 - 105 - 95 - 90 - 50 - 
109 = 108 - 106 - 104 - 94 - 89 - 49 - 
108 = 105 - 101 - 99 - 89 - 87 - 51 - 
107 = 106 - 104 - 102 - 92 - 87 - 47 - 
106 = 105 - 103 - 101 - 91 - 86 - 46 - 
105 = 104 - 102 - 100 - 90 - 85 - 45 - 
104 = 103 - 101 - 99 - 89 - 84 - 44 - 
103 = 102 - 100 - 98 - 88 - 83 - 43 - 
102 = 101 - 99 - 97 - 87 - 82 - 42 - 
101 = 100 - 98 - 96 - 86 - 81 - 41 - 
100 = 99 - 97 - 95 - 85 - 80 - 40 - 
99 = 96 - 92 - 90 - 80 - 78 - 42 - 
98 = 97 - 95 - 93 - 83 - 78 - 38 - 
97 = 94 - 90 - 88 - 78 - 76 - 40 - 
96 = 95 - 93 - 91 - 81 - 76 - 36 - 
95 = 94 - 93 - 92 - 91 - 90 - 89 -
94 = 93 - 92 - 91 - 90 - 89 - 88 -
93 = 92 - 91 - 90 - 89 - 88 - 87 -
92 = 91 - 89 - 87 - 77 - 72 - 32 - 
91 = 90 - 89 - 88 - 87 - 86 - 85 -
90 = 89 - 87 - 85 - 75 - 70 - 30 - 
89 = 86 - 82 - 80 - 70 - 68 - 32 - 
88 = 87 - 85 - 83 - 73 - 68 - 28 - 
87 = 85 - 84 - 81 - 78 - 70 - 36 - 
86 = 85 - 83 - 82 - 74 - 68 - 32 - 
85 = 82 - 78 - 76 - 66 - 64 - 28 - 
84 = 83 - 81 - 79 - 69 - 64 - 24 - 
83 = 81 - 80 - 77 - 74 - 66 - 32 - 
82 = 81 - 80 - 79 - 78 - 77 - 76 -
81 = 78 - 74 - 72 - 62 - 60 - 24 - 
80 = 79 - 77 - 75 - 65 - 60 - 20 - 
79 = 76 - 72 - 70 - 60 - 58 - 22 - 
78 = 77 - 75 - 74 - 66 - 60 - 24 - 
77 = 74 - 70 - 68 - 58 - 56 - 20 - 
76 = 75 - 73 - 71 - 61 - 56 - 16 - 
75 = 73 - 72 - 69 - 66 - 58 - 24 - 
74 = 65 - 63 - 60 - 47 - 41 - 32 - 
73 = 70 - 66 - 64 - 54 - 52 - 16 - 
72 = 65 - 64 - 56 - 51 - 48 - 24 - 
71 = 67 - 65 - 59 - 58 - 53 - 32 - 
70 = 69 - 67 - 66 - 58 - 52 - 16 - 
69 = 67 - 63 - 59 - 54 - 39 - 24 - 
68 = 63 - 59 - 56 - 53 - 41 - 32 - 
67 = 65 - 64 - 61 - 58 - 50 - 16 - 
66 = 60 - 56 - 51 - 48 - 36 - 21 -
```

Comment: Are the numbers related mathematically to their key?

Comment: Kind of related, they are the result of a subtraction, so 151 = 136, the number used to get 136 would have been 15

Comment: But 15 doesn't appear to be related to any of the other sequences, or any of the other numbers in 151's sequence.

Comment: As I said the key and its value are the result of a subtraction

Comment: I have updated map to show linked numbers sorted

Comment: Not sure I understand how the map of numbers is created. Can it be calculated by some formula/algorithm, or is it just given as "mysterious" input data? Will the "path" of intermediate numbers between `startNum` and `endNum` always consist of precisely two intermediate numbers, or can the result array have a length distinct from two? What if, for example, there is a path from `startNum` to `endNum` with only zero or one intermediate number? Should shortest solutions be preferred?

Comment: @jeppe, the numbers aren't mysterious, for some numbers 151 as an example has a known fixed set of numbers are always subtracted to produce its linked numbers, 1,3,5,15,20,60. This pattern is subtracted for many other key numbers. Yes there will always be two intermediate numbers. It will be known ahead of calling the method that at least two intermediate numbers exist between the start and end

Answer (score 2):

I would model these lists of linked numbers as a graph i.e. numbers as nodes/vertices and links between nodes as edges. The first line in your example looks as follows:

151 = 136 - 148 - 146 - 150 - 91 - 131 -

So a node 151 would be connected with a node 136, the node 136 with a node 148, the node 148 with a node 146 etc.

**EDIT**
After a comment from @cahinton I'm not sure if above interpretation of these lists is correct. Another one is that a node 151 would be connected with nodes: 136, 148, 146, 150...

You can read line by line adding nodes and edges to your graph. Each edge should have the same weight = 1. When you have a final graph you can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703871/quickgraph-dijkstra-example) to find the shortes paths between any two numbers (nodes).

The complexity of the basic implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm is O(N^2) where N - number of nodes. There are also more efficient implementations if you need it. In your case the basic solution should be enough because you will have only 151 - 66 = 85 nodes.

If you don't want to implement everything from the scratch you can use one of many graph libraries. Personally I like [QuickGraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) There is even a [question](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) how to use Dijkstra in this library.

Comment: So will this then allow me to quickly find 2 numbers which link between startNum and endNum?

Comment: Yes it will. Your graph is quite small and Dijkstra's algorithm will calculate the shortest path in the time close to nothing.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski Are you sure of the linkage?  The way I'm reading it, node 156 would link to nodes 136, 148, 146, 150, 91, and 131.  Dijkstra's algorithm would still work, but the graph would be built differently.

Comment: @cahinton When I wrote my answer I was sure about that but now I'm not ;) You might be right and it is a question to the author.

Comment: As you can now see there's a pattern to the linked numbers if this would help